# sfdx force source convert not allowing spaces in names

Tags: convert, sfdx-plugin

I'm using SFDX on a Windows machine.

The following command is giving me errors when running from a bash terminal:

```
sfdx force:source:convert -d mdapi -n 'My Alias'
```

It keeps returning this error:

```
'D:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
 operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried using double quotes as well, but the result is the same.

Comment: can you run simple sfdx command and check whether your command prompt is recognizing it or not?

Comment: Seems like that's a classic whitespace path issue.

Comment: Using the sfdx CLI in bash on Windows, whether through WSL or other means, [is not recommended/supported](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm#sfdx_setup_install_cli_windows).

Answer (score -1):

Enclose the path in single or double quotes

sfdx force:source:deploy -x "C:\Users\tania.sen\OneDrive - SourceGitREP\GIT_SFDX\manifest\CustomMetadata_Object.xml" -l RunSpecifiedTests -r RecurringBillin_Test --loglevel fatal -c

Comment: OP mentions that they have tried both single and double quotes.